# How is this an application of Cauchy-Schwarz?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

I want to deduce the following inequality:
$$
(a_1 + ... + a_n)^2 \leq C_n \sum_{i = 1}^n a_i^2
$$
Here each $a_i$ is a real number and $C_n$ is a positive constant depends only on $n$. My first thought was just to inductively use the fact that $(A + B)^2 \leq 3 A^2 + 3 B^2$ for any real $A$ and $B$. This suffices, but apparently it follows from Cauchy-Schwarz, which is what it's stated in the book. How does it follow from Cauchy-Schwarz? Thank you!

Comment: Consider vectors $(1, \ldots, 1)$ and $(a_1, \ldots, a_n)$

Comment: true... thank you!

Comment: Your $3$s may as well be $2$s.

Answer (score 0):

Using Cauchy-Schwarz for $\mathbb{R}^n$,
$$
      |a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n| \\
      =|(1,1,1,\cdots,1)\cdot(a_1,a_2,a_3,\cdots,a_n)|\\
        \le (1^2+1^2+\cdots+1^2)^{1/2}(a_1^2+a_2^2+\cdots+a_n^2)^{1/2} \\
      = n^{1/2}(a_1^2+a_2^2+\cdots+a_n^2)^{1/2}
$$
So $C_n=n$ is good enough for what you want:
$$
     \left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k\right)^2\le n\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k^2
$$